# ProgressBar под RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Доброго  времени.

Емею  разметку  в  фрагменте:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rss_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/rss_progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:theme="@style/CircularProgress">
</ProgressBar>
```

По  всем  законам  данного  жанра  progressbar должен  появится  внизу  списка (когда  прокручиваешь  список  до конца), но  он  не  появляется. В  чем  может  быть  причина???. Если  данных  нет то  progressbar торчит  вверху  и  все  работает.

Comment: Не знаю, какие жанры читаете вы (и лучше больше их не читать вообще), но в данной разметке, по всем законам жанра android-верстки, прогресс никаким образом не появится внизу списка при прокрутке до конца. Здесь два отдельных виджета на экране. Когда первый не имеет данных - его высота минимальна (wrap_content = 0) и прогресс виден, когда в списке данные на весь экран (wrap_content = match_parent), прогресс "выталкивается" за пределы экрана. Чтобы прогрессбар появился в самом списке - он должен реализоваться через адаптер списка, разметкой экрана это никаким образом нельзя реализовать

Comment: Если  поставить  высоту ресайкла допустим 300dp то прогресс не  только  виден  но  он  и  выдвигается за  ресайклом.

Comment: Ну так правильно, он и будет виден, только при фиксированной высоте, и то в частных случаях, а если вам нужен ПрогрессБар именно в конце, вы должны его добавлять как элемент RecyclerView в самом конце списка.

Comment: почему бы не использовать SwipeRefreshLayout?

Comment: @alexmx Вы хотите сделать подгрузку списка и показывать прогресс бар в низу во время подгрузки?

Comment: Да я хочу сделать  подгрузку

Comment: Использовать  SwipeRefreshLayout хорошая  мысль. Но господа  тут  уже  дело  принципа. Мне  опытный  разраб  сказал  что  можно  сделать  с  выше указанной  разметкой. Но  при этом  надо  начать  с  малого. Сначала прикрутить  фрагмент, во фрагмент  ресайкл и прогрессбар. А  уже  полсе  прикручивать  табы  и  дравер лэйоут. А я сначала  все  прикрутил  а  теперь прогресс  вставляю. Вобещем я  сейчас  упрощенную  версию  прилржения  накидаю  и  отпишусь))

Comment: Вам нужен RecyclerView с пагинацией. Посмоирите в интернетах реализацию

Answer (score -1):

Помог android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

Comment: а как помог? интересно бы было посмотреть